# Confusion regarding the axiom schema of replacement

Tags: functions, set-theory

I've seen in various sources [such as this one](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Zermelo-FraenkelAxioms.html) describe the axiom schema of replacement involving a function:

> If $F$ is a function, then for any $X$ there exists a set $Y=F[X]=\{ F(x):x \in X \}$.

My questions are really elementary, so please bare with me.

- What exactly is the domain and codomain of $F$? Shouldn't that be specified?
- In the axiom schema, we talk about *any* set $X$. Does this mean the domain of $F$ is the entire universe of ZFC? How can any function possibly be defined on every possible element in ZFC? Is there an example that can help me grasp this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at an example. Consider the following "function" (see below): $$F:x\mapsto \{x\}.$$ This makes sense for arbitrary $x$. The corresponding instance of Replacement says that for each $A$ the class $\{\{x\}: x\in A\}$ is again a set. Note that $F$ isn't limited to $A$ in any sense, but when we use Replacement we do have to restrict attention to a "starting set."

Now - and this gets to the scare quotes around the word "function" above - $F$ isn't, properly speaking, a function. In set theory a function is a **set** of ordered pairs, and the class $$\{(x,\{x\}): x\mbox{ is a set}\}$$ is a proper class. To be precise, Replacement is cast in terms of **formulas which we think of as defining functions**. That said, talking about functions may be *intuitively* helpful.

Comment: Would the axiom be equivalent if you just replaced the predicate $\Phi(x,y)$ with the proper function $(x,y)\in f$ in the formal statement of the axiom of replacement? That is: is there a reason that we don't just use "proper functions" instead?

Comment: @PineappleFish Not at all. That modified version would have no power whatsoever: if you already know that the thing you're looking at is a genuine set-theoretic function, you can build its range directly.

Comment: Thanks I'll have to think about that.

Comment: @PineappleFish Put another way, Replacement is the axiom (scheme) which makes sure that everything that *should* be a function in fact *is*. And this gives a rephrasing which would work: roughly, for each formula $\Phi$ we add the axiom "If $\Phi$ defines a class of ordered pairs passing the vertical line test, and this class has only set-many left coordinates of elements, then $\Phi$ in fact defines a set (which is a function)."